# Linux Apache server hangs when gets multiple request

Tags: php, c++, linux, apache

I have a php website which calls a C++ executable. The C++ execuatable does some calculation and access the database and gets data and return to the website. When I run the website it works fine and gives the output but when 2 users access and run the website in the same time the website hangs in both the user side and won't return anything. Is this problem with the server or it is due to my c++ executable? Is it possible that it is because I am accessing the database inside my c++ exe so its slow and it hangs because both the request try to access the database in the same time?

Is there anything I need to change in the apache configuration? Because when one user uses at a time it works fine but when there are multiple users it hangs and does not return any output. Or is it because of the hardware configuration of the server, the cpu speed, memory?

In PHP I have called the executable using the exec($addr,$data) command. As the c++ code is too long I cannot post it here but the c++ code uses shared memory and fetches the database to get the datas if this may be the problem.

Comment: How do you call the C++ executable? Show more code (both the PHP code and the C++ one)! Also, you may want the C++ code to serialize its execution.

Comment: I have edited my question...how can I serialize the c++ code execution

Comment: I believe you mean "accessing" not "excessing" the database from your C++ code. Please edit your question to explain much more how and why. Show the relevant C++ code. You could use semaphores, see [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html)